# Extending classes with generics in PHP using docblocks and proper type hinting in implmentation class functions

Tags: php, laravel, generics, inheritance, docblocks

I'm trying to make a generic Laravel authorization policy since its repetitive to write checking for a permission in the corresponding format:

- {model}_view
- {model}_store
- {model}_update
- {model}_delete
- {model}_restore
- {model}_force_delete

This is what my `PermissionService` is returning.

The only thing that I'm struggling with is extending it and having proper typehinting for the model being checked without using more docblocks (in the implementation class).

```php
<?php

namespace App/Policies;

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Services\PermissionService;

/** @template TModel of Model */
abstract class BasePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function viewAny(User $auth): Response|bool
    {
        return $auth->can(PermissionService::viewPermission($this->model()));
    }

    /** @param TModel $model */
    public function view(User $auth, $model): Response|bool
    {
        return $auth->can(PermissionService::viewPermission($this->model()));
    }

    public function create(User $auth): Response|bool
    {
        return $auth->can(PermissionService::createPermission($this->model()));
    }

    /** @param TModel $model */
    public function update(User $auth, $model): Response|bool
    {
        return $auth->can(PermissionService::updatePermission($this->model()));
    }

    /** @param TModel $model */
    public function delete(User $auth, $model): Response|bool
    {
        return $auth->can(PermissionService::deletePermission($this->model()));
    }

    /** @param TModel $model */
    public function restore(User $auth, $model): Response|bool
    {
        return $auth->can(PermissionService::restorePermission($this->model()));
    }

    /** @param TModel $model */
    public function forceDelete(User $auth, $model): Response|bool
    {
        return $auth->can(PermissionService::forceDeletePermission($this->model()));
    }

    /** @return class-string<TModel> */
    abstract public function model(): string;
}
```

So I've tried a generic called `TModel` in the docblocks but when using it in the implementation class shown below, it would still think it's a default Eloquent Model.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;

/** @template TModel of User */
class UserPolicy extends BasePolicy
{
    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function view(User $auth, $model): Response|bool
    {
         // When hovering/click on $model, it still remains an Eloquent model instead of User
         
         return parent::view($auth, $model);
    }

    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function model(): string
    {
        return User::class;
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong in overwriting/defining the `TModel` generic?
Or are there any totally different suggestions? Possibly for allowing the parameter type natively (best solution)?

If it helps, the IDE that I'm using is PHPStorm (newest version).

Comment: Since there's no actual support for generics in the PHPDoc standards, providing some more information on your environment would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried `/** @param TModel $model */` in the concrete class? Also, possibly a dumb question since I haven't looked much into what generics offer, but would it not be simpler to have a method signature like `public function view(User $auth, Model $model): Response|bool` in the abstract class and then `public function view(User $auth, User $model): Response|bool` in the concrete class? This also gives PHP actual enforcement abilities instead of relying on your IDE.

Comment: If I implement in the abstract class (`BasePolicy` in my example) 

`public function view(User $auth, Model $model): Response|bool`

And in the concrete class (`UserSettingPolicy` in my example)

`public function view(User $auth, UserSetting $model): Response|bool`

I get the following error: `Declaration must be compatible with BasePolicy->view(auth: \App\Models\User, model: \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model) `


And yes my `UserSetting` model extends `Model`.

Comment: Of course adding `/** @param TModel $model */` in the concrete class works. But doesn't that defeat the purpose of the generics?

The way I'm used to them in typescript, this seems like I'm repeating myself.

For that to work I could just use no generic at all and just add typehinting through docblocks in the concrete class.

Comment: Right, LSP. It's been a long time since I did that stuff in school lol. I would guess your IDE, whatever it is, is interpreting `@inheritdoc` more literally than you expect. It still seems to solve your problem though, since you're repeating the same line for every method in every class, whether it's `@inheritdoc` or `@param TModel $model`